# TYPO3 render content object element

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm writing an extBase extension but came to a problem with rendering records. Maybe I'm missing something, but if I did I guess I should be getting errors.

The code is part of the extension repository:

```
$conf = array(
    'tables' => 'tt_content',
    'source' => 21449, //actually here is variable for content uid but in given example i have this id
    'dontCheckPid' => 1
);

$cObject = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer');
$cObject->cObjGetSingle('RECORDS', $conf);
```

`var_dump` returns an empty string, but I also tried this:

```
$cObject->RECORDS($conf);
```

and

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->cObj->RECORDS($conf);
```

resulting in an empty string, too.

When I check the database I find a record with that id, it's not hidden or deleted. The cType is `textpic`.

I suppose I could render it manually but that will be harder since I would have to write code for each cType we have in use.

Can anybody help here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check extension called "vhs"? With it you will be able to render content elements with Fluid

Comment: so you mean like : <v:content.render contentUids="{0: 21449}" render="1"/>

Comment: Yes, something like that. There is possibility that you will not need "render" option